# Creating a blog (using DW), how to make a appear "No comments" instead of empty styled DIVS?

Tags: php, database

I am a webdesigner student, mainly working with Dreamweaver (HTML, CSS and few PHP). Right now I am creating a project for the school: one blog. One blog that have articles, and comments to that articles. I already created the PHP pages, the database (using PHP MyAdmin / MySQL), made some queries and start testing it. Until I found a problem that I would like to have some help to solve (if possible). When I created my database I added comments to most of the articles, to test if was all ok... and yes, all run well on the browsers. But then I deleted all the comments from one of the articles, and tested it again... and right now I have there a couple of Styled Divs (Backgrounds, borders) simple empty. I would like to know, how i can make these Styled Divs disappear, and replace it by something else ("No comments" for example).

Thank you, for any help that any of you can provide me.
Kadonga

Comment: You should really see something like "Undefined variable $comment" in that div so I would suggest turning on PHP errors as this will give you clues when developing: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 1):

You could have a MySQL query to find out if there are any comments for the article like this:

`SELECT count(*) as count FROM comments WHERE article_id = 1`

Then you would save the result `count` in a php variable, e.g. `$count` and test it before outputting the `div`s

```
<?php
if ($count > 0):
?>
<!-- put php loop and html for comments here !-->
<?php
else:
?>
no comments available
<?php 
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel you would have an easier time using a CMS such as Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla, etc. and construct your interface there, then hook in your pages. If you're completely against doing that, make a condition in your PHP code that reads from the database, and if `comments IS NULL` then `echo "No Comments"`

You can do this by doing:

```
$sqlConnect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');     
$query = sprintf(SELECT * FROM comments WHERE value IS NOT NULL); 
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!result) 
{ 
//Your code to print "No Comments" 
}
```